# CSS - Dropdown Sub-Menu not correctly aligning below parent button even with absolute positioning

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, submenu

Title fairly explanatory.

My dropdown submenus are not aligning exactly to the bottom of the parent list item element.

The li has a relative position, and the submenu has an absolute position, and I've tried positioning the submenus 100% from the top of the parent, which makes it appear about half way down the parent li. Equally, I've tried using top 175%, which works fine on my screens, but not on others. Surely setting it to be 100% from the top of the parent should be working

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,700");
body,
html {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
}

nav {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding: 0 2vw;
  background: rgba(232, 227, 227, 1.05);
}

nav ul {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline;
}

nav>ul:last-of-type {
  float: right;
}

nav>ul>li {
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav ul>li>a,
nav ul>li>a:focus {
  color: #000;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 13px;
  display: table-cell;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all linear 0.1s;
  -webkit-transition: all linear 0.1s;
  -moz-transition: all linear 0.1s;
}

nav ul>li>a>span {
  margin-left: 10px;
  transition: all linear 0.1s;
  -webkit-transition: all linear 0.1s;
  -moz-transition: all linear 0.1s;
}

nav ul ul.submenu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  top: 100%;
  background: rgba(232, 227, 227, 1.05);
  z-index: 99;
}

nav ul ul.submenu li,
nav ul ul.submenu li a {
  width: 200px;
}

nav>ul>li:hover ul.submenu {
  display: inline-block;
}

nav ul>li:hover>a {
  color: #fff !important;
  background: #ce0000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul.submenu>li:hover>a,
nav ul.submenu>li>a.active {
  background: rgba(206, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
```

```html
<nav id="navbar" class="navigation">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="/home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/personaldetails">Personal Details</a>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="/yourmoney">My Money</a></li>
        <li><a href="/mydetails">My Details</a></li>
        <li><a href="/admindetails">Admin Details</a></li>
        <li><a href="/contracts">Contracts</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/company">Company</a>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="/taxsettings">Tax Settings</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/invoice">Invoices</a>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="/invList">View All Invoices</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/contact">Create Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="/expenses">Expenses</a>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="/expenselist">View All Expenses</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/payslips">Payslips</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eb5xkLcj/3/)

Comment: Your fiddle uses `top: 35%`. When I replace that with 100%, it looks to me as if that should be what you want. If it is not - then you need to describe better what your issue with this is.

Comment: Sorry, that was just a typo from when I tried fixing it using px not %. Top 100% should be working, but as I said in the post, it's not correctly aligned to the bottom of the parent li, it's slightly above and changes depending on the screen it's viewed on for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the `li` formatted as `inline`, and that’s what messes this up.

Using your browser dev tools, you can clearly see that the links inside are higher than your `li`.

Make your `li` `inline-block` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Add Top 100%

```
nav ul ul.submenu
{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 100%;
    list-style: none;
    background: rgba(232, 227, 227, 1.05);
    z-index: 99;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/eb5xkLcj/2/

Comment: Did you even read my post? I said I'd done that and it hadn't worked properly. It's not correctly aligned

Answer (score 0):

Add Top 37px

```
nav ul ul.submenu {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: 37px;
      list-style: none;
      background: rgba(232, 227, 227, 1.05);
      z-index: 99;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

i checked your fiddler and found the solution for you.
Should change top position for the element:

```
nav ul ul.submenu
{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 35px; // HERE
    list-style: none;
    background: rgba(232, 227, 227, 1.05);
    z-index: 99;
}
```

Also check that you have top: 100% 2 times.

Answer (score 0):

In the file **`bootstrap.min.css`**  line no -1982

```
 .dropdown-menu {
     position: absolute;
     /*top: 100%;*/  this is the change hide this top:100%
 }
```